# Permalinks and redirects

Tags: wordpress, redirect, permalinks

I would like to change the permalink from `/%category%/%postname%/` to `/%category%/%postname%-%post_id%/`

How to set up a redirect correctly?

Tried setting it up through the Redirection plugin, but I don't know how to properly configure the rule.

Or maybe the function is easier to write?

Comment: This might qualify as a programming question and get an answer her, but you would be much more likely to get an answer at [wordpress.se] if you take out the part asking about plugins which they don't do there.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `/wp-admin/options-permalink.php`

Select Custom Structure and insert this rule.

`/%category%/%postname%-%post_id%/`

And save changes. After this use this

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'append_id_to_url');

function append_id_to_url() {
 if ( is_single() ) {
    global $wp;
    $current_url = home_url(add_query_arg(array(), $wp->request)); // Get the current URL
    $article_id  = get_the_ID();
    wp_redirect( $current_url . '-' . $article_id . '/' );
    exit;
}
```

}

Comment: Will that redirect the old URLs?

Comment: And when going externally via a direct link, how will the page type be determined?

Answer (score 0):

I did this way

```
function rudr_post_permalink($url)
{
    $request_uri = urldecode($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    $the_slug = basename(parse_url($request_uri, PHP_URL_PATH));

    if ($the_slug)
    {
        $args = array(
            'name' => $the_slug,
            'post_type' => 'post',
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'numberposts' => 1
        );
        $my_posts = get_posts($args);

        if ($my_posts):
            $post_url = get_post_permalink($my_posts[0]->ID);
            wp_redirect($post_url, 301);
            die();
        endif;

    }
}

add_filter('template_redirect', 'rudr_post_permalink');
```